# jQuery only displaying last element of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I have a `jQuery`/`JavaScript` project when in order to get a list of results you have to loop through an array. I'm using the .html to display each result one by one. Each time through the loop it's suppose to show an item. This way by the time the loop is running all the results are listed as list items. However, the loop is only displaying the last array element. I'm not sure why.

```js
    var businessListings = {
      musEnt: {
        "Mark's Studios": {
          Address: "2407 Linden Street Chester, Pa 19013",
          PhoneNumber: "267-808-4256",
          Website: "www.markstudios.com",
          Specialty: "R&B, Hip Hop"
        }, // line ends Mark's Studios info
        "CC Moore Recording Studio": {
          Address: "1420 Melrose Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
          PhoneNumber: "267-615-2009",
          Website: "www.ccmoorestudio.com",
          Specialty: "All Genres"
        } // line ends CC Moore Recording info
      },// line ends musEnt category
      paint: {
        "Ulysses's Paint": {
          Address: "2201 Edgmont Avenue Chester Pa 19013",
          PhoneNumber: "267-298-0845",
          Website: "www.ulyssespaint.com",
          Specialty: "Mixing Paint, Selling All Paint Types"
        }, // line ends Ulysses's Paint info
        "Dock Paint Supplies": {
          Address: "1007 W. 7th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
          PhoneNumber: "484-318-5190",
          Website: "N/A",
          Specialty: "All Paint Type Supplies"
        } // line ends Mark's Studios info
      }, // line ends paint category info
    }; // line ends "multi-dimensional" array object
   
    var selectedCategory;
    var textNameOfBusinessCategorySelected;
    var nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory;
    function businessListingResults(databaseList) {
      selectedCategory = $("#select-business-listing option:selected").val();
      textNameOfBusinessCategorySelected = $("#select-business-listing option:selected").text();
      nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory = databaseList[selectedCategory];
      for (findBusinessNamesUnderCategory in nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory) {
           $("#listingResults").html("<li>" + findBusinessNamesUnderCategory + "</li>");
           console.log(findBusinessNamesUnderCategory);
      } // line ends for in loop
    } // line closes function
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="title">Select a Category from the drop down menu to check your local businesses</h4>
      <select id="select-business-listing" name="submitted[select_your_program]" class="select-a-business">
        <option value="musEnt">Music and Entertainment</option>
        <option value="paint">Paint</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <button class="listingsBtn" onclick="businessListingResults(businessListings)">Search Listings</button>
    </div>
    <p id="listingResults"></p>
```

Comment: That's what `html()` does.  It replaces the contents, not append.  If you want append, use `append()`   https://api.jquery.com/html  https://api.jquery.com/append

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you very much

Comment: If you get it to work, feel free to summarize how you fixed your issue as an answer.  Otherwise, consider removing the question as it was essentially a simple method change.

Answer (score 1):

It was a matter of method change. I had to use .append() instead of .html()